# Measuring the time elapsed gives incorrect values

Tags: python, python-3.x, mergesort, python-datetime

I am trying to measure the time elapsed (in milliseconds) for sorting an array of variable size using the mergesort algorithm but the code gives inconsistent values of time elapsed, so for example when no. of elements = 60 --> time =  16.407999999999998 ms
and  when no. of elements = 70 --> time =  0.988 ms

```
def mergeSort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
         # Finding the mid of the array
        mid = len(arr)//2
        # Dividing the array elements
        L = arr[:mid]
        # into 2 halves
        R = arr[mid:]
        # Sorting the first half
        mergeSort(L)
        # Sorting the second half
        mergeSort(R)
  
        i = j = k = 0
  
        # Copy data to temp arrays L[] and R[]
        while i < len(L) and j < len(R):
            if L[i] < R[j]:
                arr[k] = L[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                arr[k] = R[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1
  
        # Checking if any element was left
        while i < len(L):
            arr[k] = L[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
  
        while j < len(R):
            arr[k] = R[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

# random number array generator
def arrGen(num):
    myArr = list(np.random.randint(0,100, size = num))
    return myArr
    
    
def printList(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[i], end=" ")
    print()
  
  
# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    for i in range(10,100,10):
        arr = arrGen(i)
        print(f"Arr length is {len(arr)}\n")
        print("Given array is", end="\n")
        printList(arr)
        
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        mergeSort(arr)
        end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_diff = (end_time - start_time)
        execution_time = time_diff.total_seconds() * 1000.0
        
        print("Sorted array is: ", end="\n")
        printList(arr)
        print(f"\nTotal time is {execution_time}")
        print("\n\n")
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html or a third-party tool like https://pypi.org/project/simple-benchmark/

Answer (score 0):

Use a benchmarking library (e.g. [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)).

```
elapsed_secs = timeit.timeit(
    'mergeSort(data.copy())',
    setup='data = arrGen(100)',
    globals=globals())
```

Note this makes a fresh copy of the unsorted data on each pass. Otherwise the input would be sorted after the first pass.